# codeigniter get current controller in post controller constructor hook

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to get the name of the called controller in a "post controller constructor" hook:

```
<?php
function authenticate() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $controller = $CI->router->class;
}
```

But I get this error message:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: hooks/post_controller_constructor.php
>
> Line Number: 5
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: / ... /CodeIgniter-3.0rc3/application/hooks/post_controller_constructor.php
>   Line: 5
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: / ... /index.php
>   Line: 292
>   Function: require_once

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
      function authenticate() 
      {
         $CI = &get_instance();
         $controller = $CI->router->fetch_class();  //Controller name
         $method     = $CI->router->fetch_method();  //Method name
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure about this. but you can try like this.
fetch_class is used to fetch the class name and method is used to fetch the method name.

```
$this->router->fetch_class(); 
$this->router->fetch_method();
```

Comment: I've already tried that despite it's deprecated methods. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: for what you need to do this? don't have any alternative way.

Comment: I needed it for checking if the user was logged in before running methods that was not in an exception list. Yes, I found an alternative way! =)